# Convert True Values in a String to Int

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, type-conversion

```
list = ['JACOBIS','LIMANIS','FOXTROT']
word = input('enter a word in the list')
generatedword = (random.choice(list))
```

Possible Scenario When Program Run,
if the user enters FOXTROT but the word was JACOBIS:

```
print("Your word contains 1/7 correct characters")
```

Possible Solutions:

```
if word == generatedword:
    print ("your word contains 7/7 correct characters")
```

Would the in operation be suitable in this scenario? For example:

```
print ("your word contains", len(str(generatedword)), "/7")
```

or

```
print ("your word contains", len(str(word)) in generatedword, "/7")
```

Comment: No, the `in` function tells you whether one string is in another and returns `True` or `False`. In your case FOXTROT is not in JACOBIS so this would always be `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `in` is not a function it's an operator for membership checking operation.

Secondly you can not use `in` because you might have a word like `hello` and another word like `he`, and this is while `he` is in `hello` but the length of characters are not the same.

Instead you can use `set.intersection()` in order to find the common characters:

```
>>> a = "FOXTROT"
>>> b = "JACOBIS"

>>> len(set(a).intersection(b))
1
```

But note that you need to divide this by the length of `set(b)` for handling the words with duplicate characters.

Since this approach will give the counts based on the unique characters, if you want to get 2 for intersection of following example, you can use `str.count()` and `sum()` function like following:

```
>>> a = 'FOXTROT'
>>> 
>>> b = 'JACOBIS' 

>>> sum(a.count(i) for i in set(b))
2
```

This will give you sum of the count of all characters in first string that are in second one.

Comment: using `set.intersection` does not however keep track of position, so `len(set('abc').intersection('cab')) -> 3`

Comment: it also loses importance of duplicate letters so `len(set('aaaa').intersection('aaaa')) -> 1`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Indeed, and it seems that OP doesn't care about that.

Comment: Yes so a = 'FOXTROT' and b = 'JACOBIS' should have intersection of 2

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, that's a clever note, thanks.

Comment: @sawreals2 No it won't give you 2 because it use set and gives you the intersection based on unique characters.

Comment: @Kasramvd, thanks for clearing that up. If for example they both had two O's (or two of the same letter in both strings), would it be 2?

Comment: @sawreals2 "a = 'FOXTROT' and b = 'JACOBIS' should have intersection of 2" **What?** That directly contradicts the original question!

Comment: @Kasramvd assuming that `FOXTROT` and `JACOBIS` should have an intersection of 1 then you could do the `min` count between the two words as that would consistently give you the common letters: `sum(min(a.count(i), b.count(i)) for i in set(b))`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, I was just confused about the operation of intersection. It would be 2 if there are multiple similar characters in the two strings.

Comment: @sawreals2 yes so I'd assume that `arrrgh` and `rare` would have 2 `r`s in common (even though arrrgh has 3) and one `a` in common correct?  I believe `sum('rare'.count(i) for i in set('arrrgh')) -> 3` which is what I would expect reversing the order gives a different result: `sum('arrrgh'.count(i) for i in set('rare')) -> 4`, see what I said above about using `min`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, ah I see what the min is doing. If you don't use it it will add up all similar characters and if you use min it will remove duplicates (assuming one string has more of the same character than the other as in your example of arrrgh and rare).

Comment: len(set(a).intersection(b)) was good if words were entered in similar order, but did not account for words being entered backwards. For example, if the word was JACOBIS, but I entered SIBOCAJ it would say that 5 characters intersect when none are in the same place. Indexing with a for loop would be more appropriate in this case.